# Using Quaternions For Camera Rotation: FPS game with switching gravity (Gimbal Lock)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

I am a new programmer trying to create a game in Unity where movement is controlled with **WASD** keys and camera movement is controlled via the **mouse**.

One feature I want to implement into the game is the ability to change the direction of gravity.

Upon changing gravity, the wall in that direction will become the **"floor"** so to speak and the player is rotated to stay upright with the new floor.

Since the game takes place inside cubic rooms, the player can make gravity go in any of the six directions. My system works fine for gravity in the `(0, -1, 0)` direction and `(0, 1, 0)` direction but soon broke upon creating controls for the `(-1, 0, 0)` direction for gravity.

Here is my code for player and camera rotation:

```
public class PlayerCamMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float sensX;
    public float sensY;

    public GameObject camera;
    
    private float xRotation;
    private float yRotation;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Put cursor in the middle of the screen and hide it
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Get mouse input
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensY * Time.deltaTime;

        //Unity is dumb so some weird calculations are needed
        yRotation += mouseX;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        
        // //Clamp xRotation so you can't look behind yourself
        // xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
        
        //Rotate camera and player
        // camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0f);
        // gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRotation, 0f);

        switch (GameManager.Instance.gravityDirection)
        {
            case GameManager.GravityState.Down:
            {
                //Clamp xRotation so you can't look behind yourself
                xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
                camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0f);
                gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, yRotation, 0f);
                break;
            }
            case GameManager.GravityState.Up:
            {
                //Clamp xRotation so you can't look behind yourself
                xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
                camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-xRotation, -yRotation, 180f);
                gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, -yRotation, 180f);
                break;
            }
            case GameManager.GravityState.Left:
            {
                //TODO Code that doesnt work as intended

                //Gravity in the (-1, 0, 0) direction
                // Clamp xRotation so you can't look behind yourself
                xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);
                camera.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, -xRotation, -90f);
                gameObject.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(yRotation, 0F, -90f); 
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The player movement works fine for the left direction, and the camera rotation also works when facing a specific wall, but breaks upon moving the mouse up/down facing any other direction. Could anyone help me figure out what the problem could be? Mouse movement left/right seems to be working as intended

I have tried numerous combinations of changing the locations of the variables `xRotation` and `yRotation` (I know the names are confusing, it just represents the rotation relative to the **"down"** direction) and even inverted them, and this current combination is the best version I have found thus far.

**EDIT:** I seemed to find the cause of the problem. I need to alter the camera's y value in the rotation vector to have proper up/down movement, but doing this alone makes it rotate about a different axis if I directly edit this value alone as I do in my code. In the unity editor, if I manually rotate it up/down using the *rotate tool*, all three values in the camera's rotation vector change at once. After some research, I believe this is due to **gimbal lock** but I am not sure how to fix it. I have heard quaternions could help but I have not been able to figure it out. Tried using a convoluted formula to convert my Euler angle to a quat but it seems to not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should be put on a gameobject that has the camera attached. It works for any gravity direction (not just the cardinal ones), so you can pick any direction for `up`. It should essentially be your `gravity direction * -1`.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerCamMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Quaternion targetRotation;
    [SerializeField] Vector3 up;
    [SerializeField] Transform camera;
    [SerializeField] float rotSpeed = 1;
    [SerializeField] float sensX = 100;
    [SerializeField] float sensY = -100;
    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
        mouseX += deltaX;
        mouseY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensY * Time.deltaTime;
        mouseY = Mathf.Clamp(mouseY, -90f, 90f);
        camera.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(mouseY, 0, 0);

        Quaternion deltaRot = Quaternion.Euler(0, deltaX, 0);
        Quaternion absRot = Quaternion.Euler(0, mouseX, 0);

        targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, up) * absRot;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation * deltaRot, targetRotation, rotSpeed);
    }
}
```

I find sudden rotations dizzying and disorienting, so the code rotates the body slowly to the adjusted gravity.

Comment: I tried this code, and the camera movement seemed to work fine when I had gravity set in the (0, -1, 0) direction but changing it caused the camera to not rotate and stay "upright" with the up vector

Comment: Are you sure that you've tried with `localRotation`? If you only use `camera.rotation` it will do a global rotation.

Comment: Your code seems to solve my problem, however, I couldn't;t get your code for player rotation to work. Also, the code doesn't actually change the player's forward vector to face the camera, so I am trying to find a way to do that right now.

Comment: Changed code. The character should now follow the x axis rotation of the mouse.